# Yarn executable was not detected in the system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets

Rails with docker gives me error when asset precompiled.
i am trying to setup rails application with docker. everything is fine but asset precompiled issue raise during build image.

```
Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
```

### Dcoker file

> 

```
`FROM ruby:2.7.2
ENV RAILS_ROOT /var/www/quickcard
ENV BUNDLE_VERSION 2.1.4
ENV BUNDLE_PATH usr/local/bundle/gems
ENV RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT true
ENV RAILS_PORT 5000
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential \
git \
libxml2-dev \
libpq-dev \
libxslt-dev \
nodejs \
yarn \
imagemagick \
tzdata \
less \
&& rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN gem install bundler --version "$BUNDLE_VERSION"
RUN bundle config set path $BUNDLE_PATH
RUN mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT
WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT
ADD Gemfile Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
COPY yarn.lock yarn.lock
RUN bundle install
EXPOSE $RAILS_PORT
RUN ln -s $RAILS_ROOT/config/systemd/puma.service /etc/systemd/system/quickcard
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "-C", "config/puma.rb"]


`
```

How to resolve this error?